# Selium Unable to Locate Class Element

Tags: python, selenium, automation

Dear Stackoverflowers,

I'm trying to automate a CC payment process but Selenium is having a hard time identifying a specific element I want to click on.  I'm trying to click on 'REI Card - 6137' so that I can continue to the payment page. Using the inspect tool it shows the class as, "soloLink accountNamesize".  Unfortunately, there's not an ID I can go after.  When I try to search by class name I get this error in the console:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to
> locate element: .soloLink accountNamesize

Below is a picture of the site and the inspector pane with the thing I'm trying to click on highlighted in blue.  Since its my credit card and I'm already logged it a link to the page wouldn't really help you guys.

[image]

The script gets hung up on "driver.find_element_by_class_name('soloLink accountNamesize').click()"

My code is below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

import yaml
import time
conf = yaml.load(open(r'D:\Users\Matt\Documents\GitHub\YML_Files\REI_Login_Credentials.yml'))
myREIUsername = conf['REILogin']['username']
myREIPassword = conf['REILogin']['password']

driver = webdriver.Firefox(
    executable_path=
    r'D:\Users\Matt\Documents\GitHub\Executable_Files\geckodriver.exe'
)

def login():
   driver.get('https://onlinebanking.usbank.com/Auth/Login?usertype=REIMC&redirect=login&lang=en&exp=')
   time.sleep(4)
   driver.find_element_by_id('aw-personal-id').send_keys(myREIUsername)
   driver.find_element_by_id('aw-password').send_keys(myREIPassword)
   time.sleep(2)
   driver.find_element_by_id('aw-log-in').click()
   time.sleep(15)
   make_payment()

def make_payment():
    if (driver.find_element_by_class_name("accountRowLast").text) != "0.00":
        driver.find_element_by_class_name('soloLink accountNamesize').click()


    else:
        driver.quit()
```

I've tried searching by Xpath and Xpath + Class with no luck.  I also tried searching for this issue but its a fairly unique class so I didn't have much luck.  Have any other ideas I could try?

Comment: Instead of time.sleep use webdriver waits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

soloLink accountNamesize is multiple class names use the following css selector instead to click on that element.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a.soloLink.accountNamesize').click()
```

To induce waits we do

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.soloLink.accountNamesize"))).click()
```

Comment: That worked!  I tried using the CSS selector before but when I hit, "copy by CSS selector" and paste it into my code, it only pasts, ".accountNamesize".  I didn't know you had to add ,"a.soloLink" in front of it.  How did you know?

Comment: .accountNamesize would only get a class of that single name it's a compound class which is multiple class names so you need them all.

Comment: Great. Thanks.  How did you know it was more than one class?

Comment: There tends to be spaces in multiple class names.

Comment: Also try to use the waits in your code to make it more stable. And accept the answer.

Comment: Right, definitely.  As you can see from the imports section I've been trying to learn how to do waits instead of the time.seep().  I'll give your webdriverwait code a try.  Hopefully once I can get a hang of it I can get rid of the time.sleep()'s.

Comment: I understand the search by CSS method works here but is there a way I could search by class name when there's more than one class like this situation?

Comment: find_elements_by_css_selector Just add the s and it would find all a tags with the class. You can index [] or loop it if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the photo, I think that this is the `xpath` that you might want

```
//div[@id='MyAccountsDiv']//div[@id='CreditsTableDiv']//tbody//tr[@class='accountRowFirst']//a[contains(@onclick, 'OpenAccountDashboard')]
```

As you can see, this `xpath` starts off with the top-most `div` that might be unique ( `MyAccountsDiv` ) and continues to dive into the `HTML` code.

Based off of this, you could click on the link with the following code

```
xpath = "//div[@id='MyAccountsDiv']//div[@id='CreditsTableDiv']//tbody//tr[@class='accountRowFirst']//a[contains(@onclick, 'OpenAccountDashboard')]"
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath).click()
```

**NOTE**

Your error says

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [id="aw-personal-id"]
```

Maybe you can use the above technique and see if you can isolate the `xpath` for the web element instead.

Comment: I totally posted the wrong error in the original post, sorry if I caused you any confusion.  As arundeep chohan mentioned, I had to use the CSS selector and some other missing words I didn't know you had to add.  I appreciate all of your effort though!

Comment: @Hiebs915 - No problem